# How do I get a list of MediaWiki namespaces?

Tags: namespaces, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki

How do I get a list of MediaWiki namespaces? Ideally with name and number.

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Meta#siteinfo_.2F_si

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the API: `api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces`

For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces

[image: XML with list of Wikipedia namespaces]

You can also get other formats such as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces&format=json).

See also [MediaWiki documentation for more info](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Meta#siteinfo_.2F_si)